# spring mvc - preserve http header during redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to add a http header and redirecting to a external url. But somehow, the header value is read null on the external url. I know we can pass attributes, but what I need is a http header

```
    @RequestMapping("/sso")
public String sso(@RequestParam("username") final String username,
        @RequestParam("password") final String password,
        @RequestParam("TARGET") final String TARGET,
        HttpServletResponse response, Model model) {

    // validate user        

    // set response token
    response.addHeader("token", "abcd1234xyz56sa");

    // return "success";
    return "redirect:" + TARGET;

}
```

Comment: The TARGET here is a different application, so I dont think I can use session. Thinking of adding an inbound interceptor or filter on the TARGET application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible. *Request parameters* can be sent because they are part of the redirect URL. Headers are not.

You need to have an agreement with the client so that they forward any header you mark as special. There's nothing you can do on the server to force all clients to re-use a header.

<sub>You can maybe get around this with cookies, depending on what you are trying to do.</sub>