# Flask redirect POST with json content-type

Tags: python, json, http, flask

I am trying to write a flask application that lets users select some options on a page, creates json string from them, and passes it to another 'build()' function, which is a flask route.
I should also be able to POST a json directly to build().

To avoid code duplication, I tried redirecting the 'Build' button in my form using code 307 and a json **argument**.
But I want to be able to pass it just as a curl request would do it with  json **content-type** (option #1 below), so I can access the passed json using requests['json'], instead of requests.args['input']

```
def gui():
    ...
    elif request.form['submit'] == 'Build':
    return redirect(url_for('build', json=session['json']), code=307)
    ...


def build():
    input = request.json #1. curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @input.json http://localhost/build
    input = json.loads(request.args['input']) #2. curl -H http://localhost/build?input=%7B"database"%3A...
    ...
```

How do I set my redirect, response, header etc. in the gui() 'Build' section  ?

Comment: That may not be possible (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25938569/10163723), I see that you are using `session`, so you can save that json output to the session? Assuming that session is user login session. Or you return that json back to the client and let it build a new request with the data to build endpoint.

Comment: @KrerkkiatChusap - the issue is that when curl request calls the /build route directly, there is no session json available. i want the build function to handle external json content-types, so i want to internally redirect json content-type too

Comment: I mean you can check if the session is available no? if it is then you are calling the endpoint after the /gui, so just use the value in that. if it does not, then you are calling /build directly, and use whatever curl is sending.

Comment: @KrerkkiatChusap oh u mean manually check how it was called.. i was hoping to be lazy, but if no other choice, then yeah